# Async signal safety of fork()

Tags: c, linux, fork, solaris, glibc

According to Oracle's [Multithreaded Programming Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/gen-26/index.html), `fork()` should be safe-to-use inside signal handlers. But my process got stuck inside signal handler with to following back trace:

```
 #0  __lll_lock_wait_private () at   ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
 #1  0x00007f86e6a9990d in _L_lock_48 () from /lib/x86_64-linux- gnu/libc.so.6
 #2  0x00007f86e6a922ec in ptmalloc_lock_all () at arena.c:242
 #3  0x00007f86e6ad5e82 in __libc_fork () at ./nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/../fork.c:95
 #4  0x00007f86e7d9f125 in __fork () at ./nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pt-fork.c:25
....
 #7  signal handler called
```

So as `malloc` is not safe to be use in signal handler how `fork` can be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably not `fork` that's the problem, but *your* code that follows the call. (Note that stack traces can be misleading when you have a broken signal handler.)

Comment: Give us just enough code to replicate the problem. Most likely, in the process of preparing that code, you'll find the problem -- it'll be the thing you removed that made the problem go away.

Comment: but the lock is inside the fork()  - so how it's can be related to the code that come after that ?

Comment: You need to show enough code to be an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It is worrying to see malloc in the trace; that is not necessarily async-signal safe.

Comment: well i found this thead : https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4737#c23 , they had long discussion about this issue but it's not seem to be solved :(

Comment: @Eyalleshem Definitely looks like a glibc bug.  Per [the latest POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):  "**While the `fork()` function is async-signal-safe**, there is no way for an implementation to determine whether the fork handlers established by `pthread_atfork()` are async-signal-safe."  glibc should **not** be using non-async-signal-safe fork handlers.  That breaks `fork()`.

Comment: Also, why the solaris tag?

Comment: don't know why the solaris tag , jww add that while editing the question ...

Comment: The Oracle Multithreaded Programming Guide linked to is documentation for Solaris, not for Linux.

Comment: well it should be async signal safe also accroding to posix : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: fork() is (should be) async signal safe in a single thread program, but in a multithreaded program (using pthreads) it is not.

Comment: less info provided. fork() inside signal handler is fine. i will provide one example below....you can use malloc inside child code also...

Comment: Listed as a bug by RedHat:  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1422161

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now [listed as a bug by RedHat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1422161):

> **Bug 1422161 - glibc: fork is not async-signal-safe**
>
> ...
>
> +++ This bug was initially created as a clone of Bug #1422159 +++
>
> POSIX requires that fork is async-signal-safe.  Our current
>   implementation is not.

Comment: Upstream bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19703, https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4737