# _L_lock_791() when printf() called

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, printf

```
bt
#0  __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:97
#1  0x00007f8bbbc215e0 in _L_lock_791 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f8bbbc1bf60 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7f8bbbf67040, format=0xcc3ae8 "send wrapper data: gate_sid=%d,uclient_sid=%d,cmd_type=%d\n", ap=0x7f8bb69b8950) at vfprintf.c:1325
#3  0x00007f8bbbc26ffa in __printf (format=<value optimized out>) at printf.c:35
```

My program has a coredump at runtime, which I found was caused by calling the printf() library function, and waiting too long time . And I don't understand the implementation of the printf() function. What is the cause of this?

Comment: The cause is probably in the way you invoke it. Can you make a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, It happened occasionally, And I can't find the way to make it happen again. @rustyx

Comment: When is `printf()` being called?  If you're calling `printf()` from a signal handler, you can't do that.  [Footnote 188 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188) even states:  "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  POSIX does allow you to call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler, but `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.

Comment: If you are calling `fork()` from within a signal hander, [Linux is broken](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1422161) and does not allow for `fork()` to be safely called from within a signal handler.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379544/async-signal-safety-of-fork

Comment: It's not called from a signal handler, but from a thread of a thread pool. @AndrewHenle

Comment: Try `thread apply all bt` to check what other threads are doing when this happens

Comment: @王晓亮 How exactly are all calls to `printf()` done in the entire process?  It's  almost certainly called improperly somewhere for this problem to occur.  For another example:  calling `printf()` in a child process after a call to `fork()` by a multithreaded parent process.  Per [the POSIX `fork()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):  "The `fork()` function is thus used only to run new programs, and **the effects of calling functions that require certain resources between the call to `fork()` and the call to an exec function are undefined.**"

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh, Thank you for your patient! I found out that my multithread parent process called fork() and closed the file descriptor stdin and stdout before calling the exec function, probably at which point the parent process called the printf() function. I've written some logging code to verify this.