# I have a question about c with send a signal

Tags: c

## this is my code

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void handler1(int sig) {
    int pid;
    if ((pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) < 0)
        printf("waitpid error");
    printf("Handler reaped child %d\n", pid);
    sleep(1);
}

int main() {
    int i, n;

    if (signal(SIGCHLD, handler1) == SIG_ERR) {
        printf("signal error\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            printf("Hello from child %d\n", getpid());
            exit(0);
        }
    }
//    sleep(1);
    printf("Father love you!\n");
    while (1);
    exit(0);
}
```

When I run it, it shows this :

```c
Father love you!
Hello from child 7843
Hello from child 7844
Hello from child 7842
Handler reaped child 7842
```

But I think it should be

```c
Father love you!
Hello from child 7843
Hello from child 7844
Hello from child 7842
Handler reaped child 7842
Handler reaped child 7843
```

There a repetition of `Handler reaped child xx`.

If I uncomment `sleep(1);`, it will show what i want :

```c
Hello from child 7858
Handler reaped child 7858
Hello from child 7859
Hello from child 7860
Handler reaped child 7859
Father love you!
```

I dont know why the first one has only one Handler reaped child.
Please help me, thank you in advence.

Comment: You can not safely call functions such as `printf()` or `sleep()` from within a signal handler.  Doing so results in undefined behavior. You can only safely call async-signal-safe functions in a signal handler.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `sleep` is async-signal-safe (in POSIX.1-2008, anyway, I know it was implemented with `alarm` and `pause` in days of yore and wouldn't have been).  You're right about `printf`, although "you can't" is too strong (see my answer).

Comment: @zwol Interesting, that.  The [POSIX specification for `sleep()` states](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html): "In single-threaded programs, sleep() may make use of SIGALRM."  How that can be async-signal-safe escapes me.  [Linux `sleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) is also listed as `MT-Unsafe sig:SIGCHLD/linux `, despite it being [listed as async-signal-safe.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)  That seems relevant to this question.

Comment: (cont) And [Linux isn't exactly very strict in its adherence to POSIX async-signal-safety requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379544/async-signal-safety-of-fork).

Comment: @AndrewHenle `sleep` is required to be async-signal-safe in POSIX itself: see the table of "functions that shall be async-signal-safe" in the [Signal Concepts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) page of the standard.  (Surprisingly, `nanosleep` is not in this list, probably because it was optional before the -2008 rev.)  I think the license for `sleep` to make use of SIGALRM in single-threaded programs is indeed incompatible with the requirement for it to be AS-safe, and this is a defect in the standard. I might file a DR.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have not close-read the Linux manpages and cannot speak to what they do or do not say, but I can tell you that GNU libc's `sleep` and `nanosleep`, as implemented on Linux, are indeed AS-safe.  (`sleep` just converts its argument and calls `nanosleep`, and `nanosleep` is a system call.)

Comment: @zwol *sleep is required to be async-signal-safe in POSIX itself*  My two points were that Linux ignored that same requirement as it applies to `fork()` so invoking POSIX to establish what a likely Linux system *should* do doesn't have a good track record, and that `sleep()` is listed as `MT-unsafe` with regard to `SIGCHLD` which seems extremely applicable to this question.

Comment: @AndreHenle Thank u very very much.
**I have changed `printf` to `write` and  remove `sleep`. But I still get only one SIGCHLD.**
In the CSAPP book, it shows me:  I will receive two signals(the third one has been discarded),one from running, the other from pending .
Can you tell me why I get one signal,not two?

Comment: When I change the server, I get two `Handler reaped child xxxx`. I am confuesed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operating system is allowed to deliver only one `SIGCHLD` signal to tell you that several child processes have exited.  That means you need to loop calling `waitpid` inside the signal handler, something like this:

```
void sigchld_handler(int unused)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    for (;;) {
        pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
        if (pid == -1) {
            if (errno != ECHILD)
                printf("waitpid failure: %s\n", strerror(errno);
            return;
        }
        printf("child %d exit status %d\n", (int)pid, status);
    }
}
```

You need to use `WNOHANG` so that `waitpid` will fail and set `errno` to `ECHILD` when there are no more processes to wait for, instead of blocking (possibly forever).

Also, in order to make it safe to call `printf` from inside the signal handler, you need to use `sigprocmask` and `sigsuspend` in your main function, so that the signal can only be delivered when normal execution is blocked on `sigsuspend`.  Also also, never use `signal`, only `sigaction`; the specification of `signal` doesn't cover several important details that *will* bite you.

```
int main(void)
{
   sigset_t sigchld_set;
   sigemptyset(&sigchld_set);
   sigaddset(&sigchild_set, SIGCHLD);

   sigset_t unblock_sigchld_set;
   if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigchld_set, &unblock_sigchld_set)) {
       perror("sigprocmask");
       return 1;
   }
   sigdelset(SIGCHLD, &unblock_sigchld_set);

   struct sigaction sa;
   sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
   sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler;
   sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
   if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, 0)) {
       perror("sigaction");
       return 1;
   }

   /* fork loop goes here */

   for (;;)
       sigsuspend(&unblock_sigchld_set);

   return 0;
}
```

Making `main` exit when all child processes have been waited for is left as an exercise.  (Hint: you need C11 [atomic types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).)

Comment: Thank u very very much. I need some time to digest what you teach.
**I have changed `printf` to `write` and  remove `sleep`. But I still get only one SIGCHLD.**
In the CSAPP book, it shows me:  I will receive two signals(the third one has been discarded),one from running, the other from pending .
Can you tell me why I get one signal,not two?

Comment: The only thing you can be sure of is that you will get _at least one_ signal.  If your book says you will get some specific number, it is wrong.