# Having trouble using sigaction with a timer in C

Tags: c, timer, signals

This is my code. As you can see it is very simple.
I want the program print dots until it catches SIGPROF signal.
But my program seems like it's not working.
How can I fix it?

```
void handler(int code) {
    fprintf(stdout, "signal catched");
    exit(0);
}

int main() {
    struct itimerval new, old;
    struct sigaction newact;
    sigemptyset(&newact.sa_mask);
    newact.sa_flags = 0;
    newact.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGPROF, &newact,NULL);
    new.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    new.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    new.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    new.it_value.tv_sec = (long int) 3;
    setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &new, &old);

    while (1)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, ". ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This signal handler

```
void handler(int code) {
    fprintf(stdout, "signal catched");
    exit(0);
}
```

violates the standards of [**7.1.4 Use of library functions**, paragraph 4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p4):

> The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify objects with static or thread storage duration.

And as [noted in footnote 188](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188):

> Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions.

POSIX does allow the calling of async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler:

Per [** 2.4.3 Signal Actions**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03):

> ... the behavior is undefined ... if the signal handler calls any function defined in this standard other than one of the functions listed in the following table.
>
> ```
> _Exit()
> _exit()
> abort()
> accept()
> access()
> aio_error()
> aio_return()
> aio_suspend()
> alarm()
> bind()
> cfgetispeed()
> cfgetospeed()
> cfsetispeed()
> cfsetospeed()
> chdir()
> chmod()
> chown()
> clock_gettime()
> close()
> connect()
> creat()
> dup()
> dup2()
> execl()
> execle()
> execv()
> execve()
> faccessat()
> fchdir()
> fchmod()
> fchmodat()
> fchown()
> fchownat()
> fcntl()
> fdatasync()
> fexecve()
> ffs()
> fork()
> fstat()
> fstatat()
> fsync()
> ftruncate()
> futimens()
> getegid()
> geteuid()
> getgid()
> getgroups()
> getpeername()
> getpgrp()
> getpid()
> getppid()
> getsockname()
> getsockopt()
> getuid()
> htonl()
> htons()
> kill()
> link()
> linkat()
> listen()
> longjmp()
> lseek()
> lstat()
> memccpy()
> memchr()
> memcmp()
> memcpy()
> memmove()
> memset()
> mkdir()
> mkdirat()
> mkfifo()
> mkfifoat()
> mknod()
> mknodat()
> ntohl()
> ntohs()
> open()
> openat()
> pause()
> pipe()
> poll()
> posix_trace_event()
> pselect()
> pthread_kill()
> pthread_self()
> pthread_sigmask()
> raise()
> read()
> readlink()
> readlinkat()
> recv()
> recvfrom()
> recvmsg()
> rename()
> renameat()
> rmdir()
> select()
> sem_post()
> send()
> sendmsg()
> sendto()
> setgid()
> setpgid()
> setsid()
> setsockopt()
> setuid()
> shutdown()
> sigaction()
> sigaddset()
> sigdelset()
> sigemptyset()
> sigfillset()
> sigismember()
> siglongjmp()
> signal()
> sigpause()
> sigpending()
> sigprocmask()
> sigqueue()
> sigset()
> sigsuspend()
> sleep()
> sockatmark()
> socket()
> socketpair()
> stat()
> stpcpy()
> stpncpy()
> strcat()
> strchr()
> strcmp()
> strcpy()
> strcspn()
> strlen()
> strncat()
> strncmp()
> strncpy()
> strnlen()
> strpbrk()
> strrchr()
> strspn()
> strstr()
> strtok_r()
> symlink()
> symlinkat()
> tcdrain()
> tcflow()
> tcflush()
> tcgetattr()
> tcgetpgrp()
> tcsendbreak()
> tcsetattr()
> tcsetpgrp()
> time()
> timer_getoverrun()
> timer_gettime()
> timer_settime()
> times()
> umask()
> uname()
> unlink()
> unlinkat()
> utime()
> utimensat()
> utimes()
> wait()
> waitpid()
> wcpcpy()
> wcpncpy()
> wcscat()
> wcschr()
> wcscmp()
> wcscpy()
> wcscspn()
> wcslen()
> wcsncat()
> wcsncmp()
> wcsncpy()
> wcsnlen()
> wcspbrk()
> wcsrchr()
> wcsspn()
> wcsstr()
> wcstok()
> wmemchr()
> wmemcmp()
> wmemcpy()
> wmemmove()
> wmemset()
> write()
> ```
>
> Any function not in the above table may be unsafe with respect to signals.

(note that [`fork()` is broken in glibc and is **not** async-signal-safe on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379544/async-signal-safety-of-fork))

What's likely happening is that your signal handler interrupts the `fprintf()` call in this loop:

```
while (1)
{
    fprintf(stdout, ". ");
}
```

And that leads to a deadlock as the `fprintf()` in the main `while()` loop holds a lock, so when the signal handler gets called it blocks on its call to `fprintf()` waiting for the lock to come free - which it can't because the call to `fprintf()` that holds the lock was interrupted by the signal.

You also can not safely call `exit()` from within a signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. does not violate the need for 'signal' handlers to only use thread safe functions

Note: `new` is a very poor choice for a variable name due to its' being a reserved word in C++.

When posting code, always post the needed `#include` statements

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void handler(int code) 
{
    (void)code;  // to avoid compiler message about unused parameter

    write( 1, "signal catched", sizeof( "signal catched" ) );
    _exit(0);  // notice the leading underscore
}

int main( void ) // use a valid signature for `main()`
{
    struct itimerval new, old;
    struct sigaction newact;

    sigemptyset(&newact.sa_mask);
    newact.sa_flags = 0;
    newact.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGPROF, &newact,NULL);
    new.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    new.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    new.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    new.it_value.tv_sec = (long int) 3;
    setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &new, &old);

    while (1)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, ". ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

a typical run of the code results in:

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
`<several thousand characters repeating '. '>`
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . signal catched